# Where WordPress Stores The Custom Fields Values

Tags: theme-development, custom-field, metabox

I have a custom Post type called product which has a Methabox with a Custom Field Called `Price` I entered `$` for some of the products and I need to remove them from the WP table. Now can you please let me know how I can do that? I mean I need to know which table is storing the data from Metaboxes?

**Update**

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'product_details_mtbox' );

function product_details_mtbox()
{

 foreach( $post_types as $post_type ){
    add_meta_box(
        "product-detail",
        "Product Details ",
        "render_mtbox",
        $post_type,
        "normal",
        "high"
    );
    }

}
```

Comment: It makes more sense to call them post meta, it's only in the GUI they're referred to as custom fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you use native custom fields, you should look for them in wp_postmeta table (your table prefix can be different than 'wp').

Comment: Hi Mateusz Marchel, thanks for reply but the `wp_postmeta`  has not any data about price!

Comment: How do you add custom post type? If you use some plugin to add this post type it can store fields in different way. For example woocommerce use wp_postmeta to store price values.

Comment: I have made a very simple plugin by myself for adding the CPT to theme

Comment: So how do you store your custom field? Could you provide some code?

Comment: Can you please take a look at Update? I used this code to add Custom Fields through metabox into Custom Post types

Comment: Well... yes. You write it to wp_postmeta. Just select all meta values where post_id is your post_id and check.

Answer (score 1):

Custom fields, aka. custom post meta fields, are stored in the wp_postmeta table.

Use this code to update your metas rather then going through the table. Modify the condition to target a certain post or a certain meta value:

`$args = array('post_type' => 'product');
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
foreach($query->posts as $post) {
   $meta =  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true);
   if ($post->ID == '85' && $meta == '$') { // Set search condition here
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', '100'); //change meta value here
   }
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you made the plugin yourself, you really should know where you are storing the data.

Mateusz is correct, in that custom fields are normally stored in the postmeta table.